# Como fazer lista de detalhes de um produto especifico

Tags: php

há uma área no meu sistema em que o usuario vê uma lista de produtos, ao clicar no produto ele pode ver os detalhes dele. Minha duvida é como fazer essa página de detalhes. Como vou pegar o codigo espeficico de um produto para que o sistema saiba que é desse produto que tem que buscar no banco seus detalhes?

tentei fazer dessa maneira (não está encontrando a pag):

MProjetos.php

```
<?php
$usuario=$_SESSION['email'];

 require_once 'Classes/ProjetosVO.php';
require_once 'Classes/ProjetosDAO.php';


 $objBDProjeto=new ProjetosDAO();
$objProjeto= new ProjetosVO();

 $rsProjeto= $objBDProjeto->ListarProjetos("1");
 $tblProjeto= mysqli_fetch_array($rsProjeto);

 $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bdpi');


  ?>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/eb2dfeaa2c.js"></script>
 <br>
 <br>
 <center><h1 class="Titulo">Meus Projetos</h1></center>
 <center>
 <br>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
<?php
include 'FormCadastraProjeto.php';
?>
  <?php
while($tblProjeto= mysqli_fetch_array($rsProjeto)){

 $query = "select cor_PROJETO from usuarios U, projetos P where email_USUARIO like '$usuario' and U.email_USUARIO=P.responsavel_PROJETO";
 $resource= mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
 $resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($resource);
 $cor = $resultado['cor_PROJETO'];
    ?>
  <a href="Projeto.php&codProjeto=<?=$tblProjeto['codigo_PROJETO'];?>" style="color: <?php echo $cor; ?>"><h1><i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i></h1>

    <?php
    $projeto=$tblProjeto['nome_PROJETO'];
    echo $projeto;

    ?>
  </a>

    <?php
               }
               ?>
```

Projeto.php
(para onde o a href deveria levar)

```
<?php

$usuario=$_SESSION['email'];

 require_once 'Classes/ProjetosVO.php';
 require_once 'Classes/ProjetosDAO.php';
 require_once "Classes/BancoDAO.php";

 $objBDpi = new BancoDAO(); 
 $objBDpi->AbreConexao();

 $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bdpi');

 $codProjeto=$_GET['codProjeto'];

 $sqlDetalhes= "Select * from projetos where codigo_PROJETO='$codProjeto'";//montando select

  $rsDetalhes= mysqli_query($mysqli,$sqlDetalhes) or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));//
  $tblDetalhes= mysqli_fetch_array($rsDetalhes);


?>

oi
```

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta esta bem vaga mas vamos lá.
Acredito que estes produtos estejam em um banco de dados, você precisa ler o banco e escrever estas descrições em algum lugar do HTML.
Por exemplo no cabeçario da página vc faz isso depois da conexão com a base de dados

```
$proc_descricao = mysql_query("select * from produtos where id='".$id_produto."'");
$pega_procutos = mysql_fetch_array($proc_descricao);
```

Dentro de uma div por exemplo

```
<div>
 Nome_Produto - <? echo $pega_procutos['nome']; ?>
 Peso_Produto - <? echo $pega_procutos['peso']; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Seria mais simples usar `<?=$pega_procutos['nome']; ?>`, menos código, mesmo efeito.

Comment: A pergunta não tinha este monte de códigos na hora que respondi. kkk

Comment: Conserta o link `<a href="Projeto.php?codProjeto=<?=$tblProjeto['codigo_PROJETO'];?> >`.

Comment: Obrigadoo kkkkkk